# Interval of convergence of $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty\ln(1+\frac{x^2}{n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to determine the convergence interval of the $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty\ln(1+\frac{x^2}{n})$  function series? The required condition is proven, it can be convergent, but where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the series is convergent at the origin only. Otherwise (for small $x$) $\log (1+x^2/n)$ is bounded below and above by constant times $x^2/n,$ so diverges by comparison with harmonic series, and for large $x$ the terms are larger than they are for small $x,$ so you are even worse off.

If you are perverse, you can also use the integral test. Integrating the function (with respect to $n$) gives:

$$x^2 \log \left(n+x^2\right)+n \log \left(\frac{n+x^2}{n}\right).$$

Both terms are positive, and the first term clearly blows up.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\ln(1 + t)\sim t$ as $t\to 0$.  So
$$\ln(1 + x^2/n) \sim{x^2/n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Direct comparison test:

$$0<t<x^2\implies\ln(1+t)>t\ln(1+x^2)$$

And so we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}n\right)>x^2\ln(1+x^2)\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n$$

And we know that the harmonic series diverges, hence so does this series.